# testing to see if a stack is empty/full with IsEmpty() & isFull() JUnit test

Tags: java, stack, junit5

I'm trying to write an isEmpty() and an isFull() method that checks to see if a stack is empty or if it has values in it. I'm not sure how to write the methods so that all tests return as successes. Here is the code for the class and methods:

```
public class stack {
    
    private int top;  
    private int maxSize; 
    private String stackItems[]; 
    
    //default no-args constructor
    public stack() {
        this.maxSize = 5; 
        this.top = -1; 
        this.stackItems = new String[maxSize];
    }
    
    //allows you to set the max size of the stack
    public stack(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        this.top = -1; 
        this.stackItems = new String[maxSize];
    }
    
    //I have two tests for this method: testIsFullFalse and testIsFullTrue
    public boolean isFull() {
        return top == maxSize -1; 
    }

    //Two tests for this method: testIsEmptyFalse and testIsEmptyTrue
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // In progress  
        return top != maxSize -1;
    }
```

Here are the tests:

```
    @Test
    void testIsEmptyTrue() {
        // ARRANGE
        stack myStack = new stack(1);
        boolean actual, expected;
        // ACT
        actual = myStack.isEmpty();
        expected = true;
        // ASSERT
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    @Test
    void testIsEmptyFalse() throws StackFullException {
        // ARRANGE
        stack myStack = new stack(1);
        String item = "Java is Fun!";
        boolean actual, expected;
        // ACT
        myStack.push(item);
        actual = myStack.isEmpty();
        expected = false;
        // ASSERT
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    @Test
    void testIsFullTrue() throws StackFullException {
        // ARRANGE
        stack myStack = new stack(1);
        String item = "testing";
        boolean actual, expected;
        // ACT
        myStack.push(item);
        actual = myStack.isFull();
        expected = true;
        // ASSERT
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }

    @Test
    void testIsFullFalse() throws StackFullException {
        // ARRANGE
        stack myStack = new stack(1);
        boolean actual, expected;
        // ACT
        actual = myStack.isFull();
        expected = false;
        // ASSERT
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
```

Right now, testIsEmptyTrue() and testIsFullFalse() come back as successes, and testIsEmptyFalse() and testIsFullTrue() come back as failures. I want them all to come back as successes. Any pointers on how to fix the methods?

Comment: Obviously there is something wrong with the `push()` method. Your question is incomplete without it.

Comment: Your mehtod `isEmpty()` is poorly named, because (judging by your impl) it tests not if the object is actually empty, but rather if it's not full. I would suggest either aligning the impl with the name, or simply changing the impl to `return !isFull();`

Answer (score 0):

A little hard without seeing the push method, but the problem might be here:

```
//Two tests for this method: testIsEmptyFalse and testIsEmptyTrue
public boolean isEmpty() {
    // In progress  
    return top != maxSize -1;
}
```

The `isEmpty()` method will always return true unless `top` **does** equal `maxSize -1`.

For a method called "isEmpty", how about something like this:

```
private static final int bottom = -1;
private int top = bottom;  
private int maxSize; 
private String stackItems[]; 

//default no-args constructor
public stack() {
    this.maxSize = 5; 
    //this.top = -1; 
    this.stackItems = new String[maxSize];
}

//allows you to set the max size of the stack
public stack(int maxSize) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
    //this.top = -1; 
    this.stackItems = new String[maxSize];
}

...

//Two tests for this method: testIsEmptyFalse and testIsEmptyTrue
public boolean isEmpty() {
    // In progress  
    return top == bottom;
}
```